# How to compute limit to infinity of an exponential in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, singularity

My question originates from trying to find the following limit:

$$
\lim_{z\to\infty} e^{-z^2}
$$

**Disclaimer**: before getting into details, I want to point out that English isn't my first language, so I apologise for grammar mistakes, and that I'm a Physics student who is fairly new to this branch of mathematics.

I've found countless questions on this site dealing with much tougher exercises, but nothing that takes into account the very basic details of each step in calculating this kind of limits. On the other hand, my textbooks (LaTeX notes from two different professors, where I found the exercise, and John B. Conway's second edition of *Functions of One Complex Variable I*) all show a very meticulous approach to the subject (**not** the limit - the exercise I'm dealing with has no solution anywhere in my notes), in which I can't seem to get a solid understanding of the whole process. I just get lost in a lot of computation and theory.

The limit written above comes right after a section on singularities, as an exercise on singularities going to infinity. First of all, I can't figure out whether $\infty$ is an actual singularity for $e^{-z^2}$, nor if this is required to know. My thought process started with writing the Taylor series expansion, which I reckon should be in fact its Laurent series expansion:

$$
\lim_{z\to\infty} e^{-z^2} = \lim_{z\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\left( -z^2 \right)^k}{k!} = \lim_{z\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\left( -1 \right)^k}{k!} z^{2k}
$$

At this point, I find it ambiguous to require $z\to\infty$, since the professor is prone to typos; I thought that maybe he intended to write $|z|\to\infty$ instead. I'm not sure, maybe the limit makes sense in both cases. Anyways, I had two ideas:

1. case: $|z|\to\infty$. I just write explicitly: $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$ with $\rho\to\infty$. I guess the limit doesn't exist, since its absolute value goes to infinity but there's no condition on $e^{i\theta}$. Moreover, it oscillates, thanks to $(-1)^k$.
2. case: $z\to\infty$. I have no clue how to proceed. I think one can make some assumptions, but I have no idea how to find the exact value of the limit.

For the record, WolframAlpha computes $0$ as the result.

Comment: Wolfram gives $0$ probably because does not consider $z$ as a complex variable

Comment: They mean $z \to \infty$. For complex $z$ this means that $\frac1z \to 0$. There  is a nice geometric interpretation of this using the Riemann sphere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere

Comment: In the complex plane we must allow $z \to \infty$ in any direction.  Try along the positive imaginary axis.  If $z=ti$, with $t>0$ real, then $e^{-z^2} = e^{t^2}$, and that certainly does not go to $0$ as $t \to +\infty$.

Comment: In Maple, `limit(exp(-z^2),z=infinity)` yields $0$, but `limit(exp(-z^2),z=infinity,complex)` yields "undefined".  I imagine Wolfram Alpha has similar capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we should understand what is the meaning of the expression $z\to \infty$ when $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Note that there is no $+$ or $-$ in front of $\infty$ as one sees for limits on $\mathbb{R}$. In general the expression $z\to \infty$ means effectively $|z| \to \infty$. This $\infty$ is sometimes referred to as the point at infinity. I am assuming this is the case here.
As usual one says that the limit exists if it is the same no matter the way it is approached.

Set $z=x+iy$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. $z^2 = x^2-y^2 +2i x y$. So

$$e^{-z^2} = e^{-(x^2-y^2)}e^{-2ixy}.$$

Now, if, for example, we fix $y$ and send $x\to \pm \infty$, $e^{-z^2} \to +\infty$. On the other hand fixing $y$ and sending $x\to \pm \infty$ one has $e^{-z^2} \to 0$. So the limit as $|z| \to \infty$ does not exist.

In general the behavior of $e^{-z^2}$ when $z\to \infty$ is controlled by the sign of $\mathrm{Re}(z^2)= x^2-y^2$. $x^2-y^2>0$ is the region shaded region in the following plot ($x^2-y^2<0$ is the white region).
One *can* approach $|z|\to \infty$ in a way such that $x^2-y^2 \to +\infty$ in which case $e^{-z^2}\to 0$.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

So for example one has:

- If $z \to \infty$ when $x^2-y^2 \to +\infty$,  $e^{-z^2} \to 0$.
- If $z \to \infty$ when $x^2-y^2 \to -\infty$,  $\left | e^{-z^2} \right | = e^{y^2-x^2} \to +\infty$.
- One the lines $y=\pm x$, $e^{-z^2} = e^{\mp 2 i y^2}$ oscillates.

But these are not the only ways one can approach the point at infinity. Indeed one can have (thanks to @SangchulLee for pointing this out)
$|z| \to \infty $ on the hyperbolae $x^2-y^2 = C$  ($C>0$ corresponds to hyperboale inside the shaded region, while the $C<0$  ones are inside the white region) and on these lines $\lim_{z\to \infty} e^{-z^2} = e^{-C^2}$

Comment: This makes sense; however, why do you say that the function's behaviour is controlled by the sign of $\left( \text{Re}(z^2) \right)$? I mean, how does the imaginary part not play a role? My take is that:
$$
e^{-z^2}=e^{-x^2+y^2-2ixy}=e^{y^2-x^2}e^{i(2xy)}
$$
However, using Euler's identity in the latter part:
$$
e^{-z^2}=e^{y^2-x^2}\left(\cos(2xy)+i\sin(2xy)\right)
$$
Which means that the imaginary is influential only concerning rotations, which has no role when $z\to\infty$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "the imaginary [part] is influential only concerning rotations". The point is that $e^{2i x y}$ does not have a limit when $x$ and/or $y$ go to $\pm \infty$, but the modulus of $e^{-z^2}$ is controlled by the real part of $z^2$. I edited the answer

Comment: @Icv apologies for my delaying in answering your response. I meant to remark that $e^2ixy$ only makes the vector rotate in the plane, while it doesn't change how it goes to infinity. I gave your answer a bit of time to sink in and now everything makes sense. I just needed to think about the geometrical interpretation a little more. Thank you!

Comment: You have to be careful. If the limit is taken along the path $x^2-y^2=1$, then $e^{-z^2}$ does not converge to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

For a function of a complex variable such as $f(z)=e^{-z^2}$, $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)$ means the same as $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} f(z)$. In this case, no such limit exists, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)=0$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(in)=+\infty.$

The limits that do exist are $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$, which are both equal to $0$.

Comment: You mean that the limit isn't defined when the function runs on $\mathbb{C}$, but it has an infinite value when on $\mathbb{R}$? Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cool theorem that might help you. If $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$. $z_0$ is an essential singularity if and only if there exist sequences $\alpha_n,\beta_n$ such that both $\alpha_n,\beta_n \to z_0$ as $n\to \infty$ and $f(\alpha_n) \to 0$ and $f(\beta_n) \to \infty$.

Also $z\to\infty$ just means that $|z|\to \infty$. It makes sense when you consider the Riemann sphere.

Comment: Yes! The Riemann sphere representation has been crucial in the interpretation of the limit. However, how's that theorem called? Is the proof very difficult? It seems like a good piece of equipment to tackle exercises on singularities. By the way, thank you for taking your time to answer my questions!

Comment: For the $\implies$ part you need to use Casorati-Weierstrass, but no hard machinery is required. You can also get help from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2734635/question-about-essential-singularity
For the $\impliedby$ part, it is more or less straightforward. If $f$ has a removable singularity, then $f$ can be 'corrected' to be analytic. So $\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)$ exists, so there cannot be two such sequences. If $f$ has a pole of order $k$, then any sequence tending to $z_0$ will make $|f|$ go unbounded. So $f$ has an essential singularity.

Comment: Clever. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We have the following sufficient (but not necessary) condition:

$$ e^{-z_n^2} \to 0 \quad\text{whenever}\quad \left|\operatorname{Re}(z_n)\right| \to \infty \text{ and } \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{\operatorname{Im}(z_n)}{\operatorname{Re}(z_n)}\right| < 1. \tag{*} $$

---

*Remark.* In order to see why we need extra conditions for this, consider the sequence $z_n = \sqrt{n\pi/2}(1 + i)$ and note that

$$ e^{-z_n^2} = e^{-n\pi i} = (-1)^n $$

does not converge. (Also note that $\left| \frac{\operatorname{Im}(z_n)}{\operatorname{Re}(z_n)}\right| = 1$ in this example.) More seriously, if we choose $(z_n)$ to be $z_n = \sqrt{n\pi} i$, then

$$ e^{-z_n^2} = e^{n\pi} \to \infty. $$

These two examples clearly demonstrate that $e^{-z^2}$ does not converge as $|z| \to \infty$ and we need to restrict the range of $z$ in which the limit is taken.

---

*Proof.* Returning to proving $\text{(*)}$, write $z_n = x_n + iy_n$ with $x_n = \operatorname{Re}(z_n)$ and $y_n = \operatorname{Im}(z_n)$. Then

$$ \left| \exp(-z_n^2) \right| = \exp(\operatorname{Re}(-z_n^2)) = \exp(-(x_n^2 - y_n^2)). $$

By the assumption, there exists $r < 1$ and $N$ such that $|\frac{y_n}{x_n}| \leq r$ whenever $n \geq N$. Then $y_n^2 \leq r^2 x_n^2$, hence

$$ \left| \exp(-z_n^2) \right| \leq \exp(-(1-r^2) x_n^2) $$

for $n \geq N$. Now letting $n \to \infty$ proves the desired claim.

Comment: Thanks for your proof. I'm giving it some time to sink in, as I'd like to understand it thoroughly. I feel I've got a grasp on it now. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can write the complex variable in polar form. Let $z = re^{i\theta}$ where $r,\theta\in\mathbb{R}$. Then,
$$
\lim_{z\to\infty}e^{-z^2}\\
=\lim_{z\to\infty}e^{-\left(re^{i\theta}\right)^2}\\
=\lim_{z\to\infty}e^{-r^2\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^2}\\
=\lim_{z\to\infty}e^{-r^2e^{2i\theta}}\\
=\lim_{z\to\infty}\left(e^{-r^2}\right)^{e^{2i\theta}}
$$
$z\to\infty$ is the same as $r\to\infty$ because $\left|z\right|=\left|r\right|$ and $\left|e^{i\theta}\right|=1

$$=\lim_{r\to\infty}\left(e^{-r^2}\right)^{e^{2i\theta}}$$

We know that $\lim_{r\to\infty}e^{-r^2}=0$ in the real case, so

$$=\lim_{t\to0}t^{e^{2i\theta}}$$

This limit is also 0, hence

$$\lim_{z\to\infty}e^{-z^2}=0$$

Comment: Try it with $z=re^{i\theta}$.  You forgot the $i$.

Comment: Also, $e^{ab}$ is in general not equal to $e^a e^b$, an invalid claim which you applied with $a=-r^2$ and $b=e^{2\theta}$.